# Customize ngb-progressbar, add label on top/bottom of the bar

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

Thank you for your help in advance. The image below is my desired result using `[ngb-progressbar][1]`

[image]

- Val1-val6 are array values that I want to use as label on top and bottom of the progress bar.
- Inside the progress bar I want to add a dot per value rendered.
- I've seen custom color and custom label ngb-bootstrap s/o but not with custom labels and inserting custom dots inside the bar instead of % completed. Any help would be appreciated.
- Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttrbeu?file=src/app/progressbar-height.html) with a simple arr that I want to render.